# CSS positioning absolute within absolute

Tags: html, css

**Edit**

**As I am setting `.list` using right "0", rest of positioning is auto... as I am developing this for a responsive layout, my container will not have fixed height, width... so I need to get positions using jQuery,**

```
e.g. $("#btnHideList").css({ 'right': .. based on position of list
same with top or bottom
```

I am trying to create a list which will have a hideMe button attached to its bottom or left, but I am not able to figure out which CSS technique I may use here.

http://jsfiddle.net/fwkWG/440/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id = "clickMe" style="height:100px;width:100px;background:red">ClickMe</div>
    <div class="list">my list</div>
    <div id='btnHideList' class = "btn">
       <span class="click">Hide</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#clickMe").on("click", function() {
    $("#btnHideList").show();
    $(".list").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 3000);
});
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    border-left:10px dashed darkgreen;
    background-color:green;
    height:800px;
    padding-left:40px;
}
.list {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    background-color:blue;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
.btn {

    position:absolute;
    background-color:yellow;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}


#btnHideList {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    right: 0px;
    background: rgb(117, 231, 117);
    top: 300px;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0 5px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px 0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Expecting this,

[image]

Comment: See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwkWG/448/)

Answer (score 0):

***CSS***
Hope this will do the Trick.

```
.list {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      background-color: blue;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      z-index:10;
}
#btnHideList {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100px;
      right: 300px;
      background: rgb(117, 231, 117);
      top: 200px;
      border-radius: 5px 0px 0 5px;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 40px 0;
      cursor: pointer;
    height:20px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fwkWG/447/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/fwkWG/452/) - Some changes in markup & css.

```
$("#clickMe").on("click", function() {
    $(".list").show();    
});
$("#btnHideList").on("click", function() {
    $(".list").hide();    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your css class

```
#btnHideList {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    right: 300px;
    background: rgb(117, 231, 117);
    top: 150px;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0 5px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```